# Test class not found when extending abstract test class

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, lumen

I am currently using the lumen framework (v5.6) and writing unit tests for my code.

I have a base class `TestCase`:

```
namespace Tests;

$_SERVER["http_proxy"] = "";

abstract class TestCase extends \Laravel\Lumen\Testing\TestCase
{
    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     * @return \Laravel\Lumen\Application
     */
    public function createApplication()
    {
        return require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
    }
}
```

I use this base class to write my tests, however I have two tests with a lot of overlap (they both test implementations of an interface), so I put the common logic in an abstract class:

```
namespace Tests\App\IO;

use App\io\PageDataParser;
use App\Models\AdvancedArray;
use App\Services\PageService;
use Mockery;
use Tests\TestCase;

abstract class ParsePageDataTestCase extends TestCase
{

    // Test logic here, but not relevant for the question

}
```

And finally I use this abstract class on my actual test:

```
namespace Tests\App\IO;

use App\io\JsonPageDataParser;
use App\Models\AdvancedArray;

class JsonParsePageDataTestCaseTest extends ParsePageDataTestCase
{

   // Test are here, but not relevant for the question
}
```

However when I execute `JsonParsePageDataTestCaseTest` I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Tests\ParsePageDataTestCase' not found in \tests\app\io\JsonParsePageDataTest.php on line 15

I have verified that the structure of the folders is corrected, also tried using 'composer dump-autoload`and verified that my`composer.json`has an entry which specifies a classmap to 'tests/`.

I execute my tests using phpunit.xml which loads the `bootstrap/app.php`, but I still get this error.

The `phpunit.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="bootstrap/app.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application test Suite">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
           <!-- ENV variables go here -->

    </php>
</phpunit>
```

And finally my `composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/lumen",
    "description": "The Laravel Lumen Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel", "lumen"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.3",
        "laravel/lumen-framework": "5.6.*",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "~2.2",
        "willdurand/hateoas": "~2.1",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "vinelab/neoeloquent": "^1.4.6",
        "jenssegers/mongodb": "3.4.*",
        "predis/predis": "~1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~7.0",
        "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "~2.5"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

If you need any more information please let me know.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Missing ParsePageDataTestCase  use statement after namespace declaration on JsonParsePageDataTestCaseTest.php.

Comment: @GabrielPereira, thank you for your response. But they reside in the same namespace so a use statement is not required

Comment: Can you share your composer.json autoload?

Comment: @GabrielPereira yes, I updated the question

Comment: Have you tried to load your test class putting them on psr-4 autoload as "Test\\": "tests/" ?

Comment: That did the trick @GabrielPereira, thank you!

Comment: @GabrielPereira, would you consider adding this with an explanation as answer? It might help other people who encounter this issue, since laravel claims it autoloads everything by default (and makes the composer.json correct) but apparently this does not work without additional action

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem from the Lumen installation. 
When you install laravel the tests folder comes configured as psr-4 on autoload-dev:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
...
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
...
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
```

}

But on Lumen installation doesn't as we can see bellow:

```
{
"name": "laravel/lumen",
"description": "The Laravel Lumen Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel", "lumen"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.1.3",
    "laravel/lumen-framework": "5.7.*",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "~2.2"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~7.0",
    "mockery/mockery": "~1.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
}
```

So in order for this to work you will need to change the autoload to:

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
}
```